# iPad - Documents Folder Access

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to access the document files for a particular application? Can you assume that this folder is never accessible apart from hacking it somehow or perhaps even jail broken?

I don't intend to have the app through the app store as its a business app and within the company. I just want to know how secure this Documents folder is and if its possible to access as it may contain confidential documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the contents of it end up in the user's iTunes backups — so I'd say not secure. You should encrypt anything confidential.

Comment: Thanks is it possible to encrypt images/documents on the file server level? I guess if your download from the server as an encrypted file then you could save it in the same form. When you view the file in the app thats when you would decrypt it. I guess now you need an encryption that works both on ipad and the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

The documents folder is backed up by iTunes.

Have a look at [Apple's official documentation about files on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW11).